# Javascript Adding data to array not working quite good

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I am having a problem with my code hope somebody can help me with it.

I have a HTML file with two textboxes with id:name and another one with id:lname, and a submit button. When I press the button it executes this (function add)  which is in a separate file.

```
var person = {}, people = [];

function add(){

  person.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  person.lastname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  people.push(person);
  console.table(people);

}
```

It seems to work fine the first time (It saves the values into the object and then into the array) but when I change the textboxes and press the button again, instead of saving the new values into the next position in the array it rewrites both positions with this new input duplicated

Comment: at the top of `add()`, start with `person = {}`. Or better yet, use a local variable instead of a global one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you are having the same reference of the object `person` for all positions in the array. Because of which whenever you change the value of person, it gets updated at all the places it being used. You have to create a reference for each new `add` operation. Try following

```
function add(){
  person = {}; // -------------- Add this line here
  person.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  person.lastname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  people.push(person);
  console.table(people);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I corrected my code and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Marcelo - Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a scope issue. By putting your person object declaration in your function like Marcelo suggested, you may resolve this. You're thinking that a new object is being cloned each time, but in fact it seems that the same object is being overwritten with new values. If you ran a for loop and saved your iterator to the array each time, you'd find that in the end you'd only have the last value. So it goes.

Answer (score 0):

just  initiate the `var` inside the function, so it would be able to update them every time you call the function

```
function add(){
  var person = {}, people = [];
  person.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  person.lastname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  people.push(person);
  console.table(people);

}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Everytime you add, array will be reset which means at any point of time there will be maximum 1 value in the array which is not what the OP wants.